# How to create floating Tab Bar Swift

Tags: swift, uitabbar, tabbar, pinterest

I'm trying to create a Pinterest style Tab Bar. Is it possible to customise UITabBar in that way or do you have to write a separate view to sit on top of everything if so how would you do that? It's basically just moved up with rounded corners and a shadow. How would you adjust the width of the tab bar and move it up?

[Image of Tab Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaeLE.png)

Comment: check this out pal, maybe this will work -> https://medium.com/@gemix95/how-to-build-round-tabbar-in-swift-b1cfb96b3358

Comment: Is it really a TabBar, or maybe a UIWindows added on top which might delegate to an main viewcontroller (which might be a UITabBarController).

Comment: @emrcftci Wow that was a lot easier than I expected. Thanks!

Comment: @emrcftci can you post that as an answer so I can mark it as correct

Comment: actually this is not an answer but I'm gonna modify it and post as an anwer, I'm happy to be able to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make "RoundedTabbar" than you can create one like this ->

```swift
import UIKit

class RoundedTabBarController: UITabBarController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let layer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 30, y: tabBar.bounds.minY + 5, width: tabBar.bounds.width - 60, height: tabBar.bounds.height + 10), cornerRadius: (tabBar.frame.width/2)).cgPath
    layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)
    layer.shadowRadius = 25.0
    layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    layer.opacity = 1.0
    layer.isHidden = false
    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
  
    tabBar.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)

    if let items = tabBar.items { 
        items.forEach { item in 
            item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: -15, right: 0) 
        }
    }

    tabBar.itemWidth = 30.0
    tabBar.itemPositioning = .centered
  }
}
```

> Don’t forget to type if you are using storyboard, the class name in the Identity inspector.

*PS: I'm sharing [Emmanuele Corporente's Medium article](https://medium.com/@gemix95/how-to-build-round-tabbar-in-swift-b1cfb96b3358) content as an answer please check the original article & give it some claps!*

Answer (score 0):

I created a floating tab bar library. It doesn't look exactly like Pinterest's but you could probably modify the drawing code to change the way it looks.

[Here's the repo.](https://github.com/EmilioPelaez/FloatingTabBarController)

If you want to implement it from scratch, you'll have to create your own view controller subclass, as well as a UIView subclass for the tab bar, and manage the "page" switching yourself. `UITabBarController` doesn't offer enough customization for this.